# How to get URIs by using Falcon RESTful API

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, asp.net-web-api

I m using FALCON semantic search engine RESTful API & wrote this program
But not getting the results that should respond from Search engine.Please look at code & help me.

```
package httpProject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class HTTPRequestPoster {
    public String sendGetRequest(String endpoint, String requestParameters) {
        String result = null;
        if (endpoint.startsWith("http://")) {
            try {
                String urlStr = endpoint;
                if (requestParameters != null && requestParameters.length () > 0) {
                    urlStr += "?" + requestParameters;
                }
                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();

                // Get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //HTTPRequestPoster a = new HTTPRequestPoster();//
        HTTPRequestPoster astring = new HTTPRequestPoster ();
        String param = "query=Person";
        String stringtoreverse = URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
        astring.sendGetRequest("http://ws.nju.edu.cn/falcons/api/classsearch.jsp", stringtoreverse);
        astring.toString();

        System.out.println(astring);
        //PrintStream.class.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but you never need to do `import java.lang.*;` as Java does that automatically for you. Always has.

Comment: ya that's true but it won't work after removing import java.lang.*;

Comment: Won't work after removing that?! Either you've got classes in the same package as `HTTPRequestPoster` with very badly chosen names, or the world's very strange indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the heavy lifting except two small problems:

- `URLEncoder.encode(...)` should not be used here. [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) says it translates a string into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, i.e. when doing `POST`.
- `astring.sendGetRequest(...)` instead of `astring` itself should be used as result.

Following works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //HTTPRequestPoster a = new HTTPRequestPoster();//
    HTTPRequestPoster astring = new HTTPRequestPoster ();
    String param = "query=Person";
    String result = astring.sendGetRequest("http://ws.nju.edu.cn/falcons/api/classsearch.jsp", param);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting but I need to encode string in UTF-8 format

Comment: It's Java so you don't need to do that explicitly.